# canBecomeFocused on swift 3

Tags: uiview, swift3, tvos

I'm trying to create a custom View which I need to focus. 
According to numerous Sources this is the way to go :

```
override func canBecomeFocused() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

However after converting to Swift 3.0 this no longer works.
It throws the error:

> Method does not override any method from its superclass.

If i remove the override another error gets thrown:

> Method 'canbecomeFocused()' with Objective-C selector 'canBecomeFocused' conflicts with better for 'canBecomeFocused' from superclass 'UIView' with the same Objective-C Selector.

Anyway I can make a `UIView` Selectable for TvOS?

Comment: in my swift 3 code i m able to override this property , so please try again.

Comment: im going to see if i can update xCode. it is weird I'm on 8.0 beta 4.. going 8.2 now (latest)

Comment: I m working on Xcode 8 and its working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift 3 it is change to `Instance Property`, so try like this.

```
override var canBecomeFocused: Bool {
    return true
}
```

Check Apple Documentation on [`canBecomeFocused`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622584-canbecomefocused#declarations) for more details.